# функция типа double выдает -nan(ind), а когда поменять на "int", то всё нормально работает

Tags: c++, double

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double Max(double* arr, int n, int &max) {
    if (n>1)
    {
        if (arr[n - 1] >= arr[max])
            max = n - 1;
        n--;
        Max(arr, n, max);
    }
    else {
        return arr[max];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arrSize, max = 0;
    cout << "Enter size of array\n";
    cin >> arrSize;
    double* arr = new double[arrSize]();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
    {
        cout << "arr[" << i << "] = ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Max element arr[" << max << "]=" << Max(arr, arrSize, max) << endl;
    delete[]arr;
    return 0;
 }```
````

Comment: Это код компилируется без предупреждений и ошибок?

Comment: Не к вопросу, но бессмысленно: `cout << "Max element arr[" << max << "]=" << Max(arr, arrSize, max) << endl;` — нет никаких гарантий, что `Max()`  вычислится до вывода `max` (а с С++17 есть обратная гарантия...)

Comment: Код компилируется без ошибок и предупреждений.

Comment: Harry, почему тогда при типе функции "int" все работает, вещественные числа просто округляются до целого

Answer (score 2):

Скажите, при, скажем, `n == 2` какое значение вернет **текущий** вызов `Max()`? Не тот, который будет в самом конце рекурсии, а именно *текущий*? Оператора `return` же нет... Добавьте:

```
    n--;
    return Max(arr, n, max);
}
```

И - то, что я вам уже писал, внесу в ответ: вывод

```
cout << "Max element arr[" << max << "]=" << Max(arr, arrSize, max) << endl;
```

неверный. До С++17 нет никаких гарантий, что `Max()`  вычислится до вывода `max`, а начиная с С++17 есть обратная гарантия — что вы обязательно получите в выводе

```
Max element arr[0]=
```